# Bottom - Up SLR(1) Conflict / Reduce when both applies

Tags: algorithm, parsing, compiler-construction, grammar

If I have a situation where a state in the DFA have shift/reduce conflict,
where both shift and reduce applies, let the next symbol be "t" and we have the following rules

X -> F.

Y -> F.tG

and t belongs the follow of X
What should I do in this case?
I know by definition that's not an SLR(1) Grammar but according to the algorithm shown https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNzKP.jpg, what should the algorithm do? Should it report an Error?

The algorithm says we report an error if neither (shift or reduce) applies, but what happens if both apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have detected this error when you attempted to construct the parser. The SLR parser generation algorithm must fail if there is a conflict.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PEV7Bew
I'm asking this question, because, in one of the previous exams, I'm practicing, I found this question, I'm not sure If I should report an error since both items apply.

Comment: @Abdulmajed: I don't know. It seems like a very badly phrased question, and not just because of the typo. It doesn't specify FOLLOW(F), which is important. I don't understand how `+` could be on top of the stack if the items presented are supposed to be the current state (but it doesn't actually say that those items are from the current state, or indeed even from that same state.) Unfortunately, you need to deal with badly-phrased exam questions. Sorry I can't help more. (For what it's worth, most real-world parsers will choose a legal shift action if both shift and reduce are possible...

Comment: ...but that's a heuristic. It's not part of the algorithm.

Comment: The problem in imgur.com/a/PEV7Bew seems fairly different from the original. A state in the DFA should never have two items with different symbols to the immediate left of their dot, so the preamble (assuming it's not simply wrong) must just mean that these are items *somewhere* in the DFA, not in the same state. Which is basically just saying that `E -> T + F` and `T -> F` are two productions in the grammar. Without knowing what F (and possibly T) can derive, it's impossible to know what the correct response to the given situation is.